# How can I copy data from R to a database using SQL?

Tags: sql, r, copy

I created a data frame in R, and I want to copy it to a remote data base. I copied the dataframe, but it doesn't contain values. The server is a teradata server.

What was working was to download the data using this code:

```
td_connection <- connect_teradata(type = "ODBC", datalab = "RWDS_rwds_1619")

# get the table
test101 <- tbl(td_connection, "Austria_cases") %>% collect()
```

I was able to upload the data to a remote data base using this code:

```
# worked somehow no values in destination
dbplyr::src_memdb() %>% copy_to(cntDisease, overwrite = TRUE)
```

I also tried these approaches:

```
# Doesn't create a data base at the remote server
my_db <- src_sqlite("RWDS_rwds_1619", create = TRUE)
copy_to(my_db, cntDisGene, "cntDisGene", overwrite = TRUE)

# Throws an error
write_teradata("RWDS_rwds_1619", "cntDisease", df = cntDisease, connection = td_connectionJ)

Error in rJava::.jcall(con@jc, "V", "setAutoCommit", FALSE) : 
  trying to get slot "jc" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `DBI::dbAppendTable`?

Comment: So, would it be `DBI::dbAppendTable %>% copy_to(cntDisease, overwrite = TRUE)`?

Comment: No, likely `DBI::dbAppendTable(my_db, "cntDisGene", cntDisGene)`. Or even better: `DBI::dbWriteTable(my_db, "cntDisGene", cntDisGene, ...)` where `...` are arguments needed (such as `overwrite=`). See `?DBI::dbWriteTable` and/or `?DBI::dbAppendTable`.

Comment: Thanks, r2evans. Just one more thing - I get an error when I write `DBI::dbWriteTable(td_connection, "cntDisGene", cntDisGene)`. Error is: **unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ for signature ‘"NULL"’`**

Comment: That means `td_connection` (or `my_db`, whereever you are writing to) or `cntDisGene` is `NULL`. I'm assuming the former is a connection object and the latter is a `data.frame`. Am I mistaken? (Should it be `cntDisease` instead?)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try it.